# How to define a Function which flexibly accepts subclasses of declared type

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to design a single arg function that can be applied to subclasses of the declared type:

But when I apply a function like this to a type T as below:

```
Function<? extends T,Boolean> function;
function.apply(T)
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
T cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? extends T
```

Example of the validation interface I am trying to design:

```
//Intent is that the function can be applied to T, or any subclass of T
public interface IBeanValidator<T> {
    public Function<? extends T, Boolean> getValidation();
}

//Class that implements this interface will accept validators for its type
public interface IValidateableBean<T> {
    public void validate(final IBeanValidator<T> validator);
}

//Interface for bean objects, which can be validated with validators designed
//for beans belong to this inheritane hierarchy
public interface IBean extends IValidateableBean<IBean> {
    public default void validate(final IBeanValidator<IBean> validator) {
        //compilation error occurs here. 
        validator.getValidation().apply(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `Function<? extends T, Boolean>`, you actually just want a `Function<T, Boolean>`, which *will* accept subtypes of T.  A `Function<? extends T, Boolean>` actually refers to some unknown but specific subtype of `T`, e.g. `Function<SubT, Boolean>`, which can't necessarily be applied to any `T`.

Comment: I added a clarifying example of what I want to do.

Comment: Yup, looking at that, you do want `Function<T, Boolean>`.